# How do I call a method on each object inside of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

[Gist of my full code, 31 lines](https://gist.github.com/jtara1/7d2aa09ef6fc9a7db824bf59ef1dffad)

I'm trying to convert doubles -> BigDecimal then call setScale method on each of the BigDecimal objects stored inside of an array.

```
    // convert double variables to BigDecimal inside of new BigDecimal array
    BigDecimal[] ret = new BigDecimal[]{
        new BigDecimal(area),
        new BigDecimal(theta),
        new BigDecimal(x),
        new BigDecimal(y)
    };
    // setScale on each object
    for (BigDecimal val: ret) {
        val.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    }
```

But when I print this out, it's clear the setScale function was not called on any of the objects when I print each out later.

Are the objects in the array not being mutated or saved in the 2nd for loop?

---

Update & Adjustment with Answer-Advice:

Based on Hovercraft's answer I rewrote the last bit of my code here to:

```
    double[] vals = new double[]{area, theta, x, y};
    BigDecimal[] ret = new BigDecimal[vals.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = new BigDecimal(vals[i]).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    }
```

Which does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigDecimal like String is immutable, and so just calling `setScale(...)` on the BigDecimal *object* will have no effect on the same object. For the scale to be set, you have to re-assign the result to the BigDecimal variable. For this purpose, I would not use a for-each loop, but rather a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
   ret[i] = ret[i].setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
}
```